# How to make good tag wiki excerpts for software tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I recently came across the tag [deluge](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/deluge) which apparently is a BitTorrent client. Seeing that the tag had no excerpts but a few questions I wanted to add one so that users can easily see what deluge is. I looked at the excerpt from other software tags, like VirtualBox or Notepad++ which are the following:

> Notepad++ is a free source code editor and Notepad replacement that
>   supports several languages. Running in the MS Windows environment, its
>   use is governed by GPL License.

and

> VirtualBox is a free, open source virtualization program from Oracle
>   for the x86/x86_64 architectures.

So for me it looked like tag excerpts for software are mostly a short description of the software.

So I submitted the following edit suggestion (the way deluge is described on its website):

> Deluge is a lightweight, Free Software, cross-platform BitTorrent client.

The edit was declined with the reason:

> Simply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it unless the
>   tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe why and when
>   a tag should be used.

However neither the Notepad++ or the VirtualBox tag excerpt follow this rule (they neither describe when or why to use this tag).
I don't want to question the decision of my tag not beeing "good enough" but I'm rather curious if the two mentioned tag excerpts are "invalid" too or if I'm missing something. Also should I have somehow mentioned that I got the description from the Deluge website and if so how?

Comment: [What is a tag wiki? How do I write a good one?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338)

Comment: @DavidPostill The link you posted says that a tag excerpt purpose is: "The main purpose of the tag wiki excerpt is to tell people what the tag should be used for." So the tags excerpts from notepad++ and vmware are wrong aren't they? They should be something like. "This tag should be used for the virtualization program from Oracle for the x86/x86_64 architectures."

Comment: Indeed - they could do with some tidying up. Feel free to suggest some edits :)

Comment: Agree that these are not particularly useful tag excerpts. (Not saying I haven't written similar ones, or that users generally care a lot about these, both when writing and reading them.)